# Ejercitacion de JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, function

El ejercicio me pide que formule una nueva función que utilice a autosParaLaVenta y que filtre a los autos que son 0 km (km < 100), no lo puedo resolver, si me dan una mano.
Fuimos acumulando funcionalidades para el desarrollo de una concesionaria y una nueva pide esto de que se filtren los autos que estan a la venta (Sin incluir los que fueron vendidos)

EL ERROR QUE ME TIRA ES
Al vender al auto con patente 'JJK116' y luego llamar a la función autos0KM no debe contener ese auto

```
`let autos = require("./autos")

const concesionaria = {
    
   autos: autos,
  buscarAuto : function (patente){
     for (let i = 0 ; i <= autos.length; i++){
        if(autos[i].patente ==patente){
           return autos[i]
        } else {
           return null
        }     
     }

},
venderAuto: function (patente){
   let  auto = this.buscarAuto(patente);
   if (auto) {
      auto.vendido = true;
   } 
},
autosParaLaVenta : function (){
   return this.autos.filter((function(auto){ return auto.vendido === false})
   )
},

autosNuevos : function(){
   return this.autosParaLaVenta().filter( (function(nuevo){
      return nuevo.km < 100
   }))
}
}`
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error/problema? Menciónalo tanto en el título como en la pregunta misma.